# Можно ли встроить в модель категорий модель позиций?

Tags: база-данных, mongodb, архитектура, nosql, моделирование

Есть модель Categories

```js
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    imageSrc: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    positions:[{
        name:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        cost: {
          type: Number,
          required: true
        }
    }],
    user: {
        ref: 'users',
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
    }
```

Вопрос: не отвалятся ли позиции из за их количества?

Comment: 10, 100, 1000, ... позиций?

Comment: @TotalPusher и больше естественно

Comment: Можете смоделировать и проверить ситуацию, когда десять "воркеров" параллельно обновляют цены на разные товары из одной категории? И что из этого вышло по скорости. Пожалуй, даже, пусть одна задача на обновление попозиционно всех цен.

Comment: @TotalPusher а как измерить эту скорость?

Comment: Внизу дали расчет количества вложенных документов. Вообще я вел к тому, что громадные документы долго обновляются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Максимальный размер BSON документа 16MB - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#limit-bson-document-size

Сам документ категории без единой позиции занимает 136B [image]

позиция весит 41B
[image]

Получается в одной категории поместится приблизительно 390243 позиций

Comment: Верный подход, только 16 Мб / 41 байт намного больше 396 позиций.

Comment: На моей коллекции средний размер товара 20 Кб => лимит 800 товаров.